# Problema con el ciclo while en PHP y SQL Server

Tags: php, html5, sql-server, bucles, while

Estos creando una especie de catálogo de productos clasificado por familias de productos.. Resulta que estoy usando tablas para mostrar la información, es decir, se crean las tablas por cada familia y luego se insertan los productos en las tablas correspondientes, por ejemplo, en la tabla de fontanería se mostrarán los productos que pertenezcan a la familia de la fontanería y así con los demás artículos.....
Para hacer esto en PHP estoy usando ciclos while anidados, es decir uno dentro de otro, un ciclo externo crea una tabla html para cada una de las familias de productos y el ciclo interno(que está dentro de la tabla creada por el ciclo externo)se encarga de mostrar los productos de la familia a la que pertenece.

El problema está cuando se ejecuta el ciclo interno.... El ciclo externo se ejecuta bien si el ciclo interno no se ejecuta, es decir, el ciclo externo crea las tablas para la cantidad de familias que se encuentren en la base de datos, pero si se ejecuta el ciclo interno que es el que coloca los productos de cada familia en la tabla correspondiente, el ciclo externo solo crea una tabla y no las demás. En las siguientes imágenes se ve mejor.

Este es el código fuente.

```
 <div class="container">
            <h1 class="TDTQVS">Productos</h1>
            <br>
            <?php
                include("../Scripts/MuestraFamilia.php");
                $i = 0;
                while($Fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
                    $Id_Familia = $Fila["Id_Familia"];
                    $Nombre_Familia = $Fila["Nombre_Familia"];
                    $i++; 
            ?>
            <h2 class="TDTQVS"><?php echo $Nombre_Familia;?></h2>
                <table class="table TabRegistro">
                    <th>Nombre del producto</th>
                    <th>Descripción del producto</th>
                    <th>Imagen del producto</th>
                    <th>Familia</th>
                    <th>Oferta</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <!-- Se incluye código php para mostrar los datos -->
                    <?php
                        //  //Se incluye el archivo que trae los datos
                        //  include("../Scripts/ProductoXFamiliaSelect.php");
                        //  //Se declara una variable contadora para que el ciclo no sea infinito
                        //  $i = 0;
                        //  //Ciclo que va a recorrer la tabla de los productos,mostrandolo en la tabla de la vista
                        //  while($Fila = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt)){
                        //      $Nom_Producto = $Fila["Nombre_Producto"];
                        //      $Descripcion = $Fila["Descripcion"];
                        //      $Imagen_Producto = $Fila["Imagen_Producto"];
                        //      $Nombre_Familia = $Fila["Nombre_Familia"];
                        //      $Nombre_Oferta = $Fila["Nombre_Oferta"];
                        //      $Precio = $Fila["Precio"];
                        //      $i++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php //echo $Nom_Producto?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $Descripcion?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $Imagen_Producto?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $Nombre_Familia?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $Nombre_Oferta?></td>
                        <td><?php //echo $Precio?></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                       // }
                    ?>
                    <!-- Se vuelve a abrir un espacio de código php para cerrar el ciclo y cerrar la conexion con la base de datos -->
                    <!-- Se termina el código php -->
                </table> 
                <hr>
                <hr> 
             <?php
                }
            ?>
         </div>   
    </div>
```

El ciclo interno es el que esta comentado(No se ejecuta), como resultado pasa esto:
[image]
El ciclo externo crea las tablas para cada familia, siempre y cuando el ciclo interno no se ejecute.

Ahora bien, cuando se ejecuta el ciclo interno pasa esto:

[image]
El ciclo externo solo se ejecuta una vez mostrando solamente la primera tabla, cuando debería aparecer todas las familias con la tabla correspondiente, como se muestra en la primera imagen.

Que puedo hacer para que el ciclo externo e interno se ejecuten de manera correcta y muestre los productos por familias a como se ve en la primera imagen.

Espero haberme dado a entender...Muchas gracias de antemano,saludo!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, después de notar mi garrafal error de usar un motor de BD diferente, trato de corregir...

Para hacer una consulta a `sql server`, te falta:

- Agregar el segundo parámetro en la consulta `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC`. [Aquí la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)
- Nombrar las variables de forma diferente en cada uno de los ciclos, en vez de usar `$fila`, utiliza los nombres de las tablas, por ejemplo, `$familia` y `$producto`

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="TDTQVS">Productos</h1>
    <br>
    <?php while( $familia = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) : ?>
        <h2 class="TDTQVS"><?= $familia["nombre_familia"]; ?></h2>
        <table class="table TabRegistro">
            <th>Nombre del producto</th>
            <th>Descripción del producto</th>
            <th>Imagen del producto</th>
            <th>Familia</th>
            <th>Oferta</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <?php
                $idFamilia = $familia["id_familia"];
            ?>
            <?php while( $producto = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $producto["nombre_producto"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $producto["descripcion_producto"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $producto["imagen_producto"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $producto["id_familia"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $producto["nombre_oferta"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?= $producto["precio"]; ?></td> 
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table> 
        <hr>
        <hr> 
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

---

---

**Esta segunda parte la dejo solo de manera informativa, por si es útil para alguien...**

Personalmente lo haría con `foreach` en lugar de `while` ya que se itera tantas veces como objetos hayan y no te preocupas por incrementar una variable en cada iteración. Si tienes bien declaradas tus funciones, debería funcionar de maravilla.

Te dejo un ejercicio completo a modo de ejemplo. Hice la prueba completa para comprobar que funciona.

Ojo, esto es solo un ejemplo, no estoy usando consultas preparadas ni maquetación en `html` ya que no es la finalidad de tu pregunta, debes adaptar tu código para que no sea vulnerable a ataques de inyección `SQL`.

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

    //Setear la colación utf8
    $mysqli -> set_charset("utf8");

    // comprobar la conexión
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM familias";
    $familias = $mysqli->query($sql1);
?>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="TDTQVS">Productos</h1>
    <br>
    <?php foreach($familias as $key => $familia) : ?>
        <h2 class="TDTQVS"><?= $familia["nombre_familia"]; ?></h2>
        <table class="table TabRegistro">
            <th>Nombre del producto</th>
            <th>Descripción del producto</th>
            <th>Imagen del producto</th>
            <th>Familia</th>
            <th>Oferta</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <?php
                $idFamilia = $familia["id_familia"];
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_familia = $idFamilia";
                $productos = $mysqli->query($sql2);
            ?>
            <?php foreach($productos as $key => $producto) : ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $producto["nombre_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["descripcion_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["imagen_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["id_familia"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["nombre_oferta"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["precio"]; ?></td> 
              </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table> 
        <hr>
        <hr> 
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<!-- cerrar la conexión -->
<?php $mysqli->close(); ?>
```

**El resultado es el siguiente:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego código usando `while` con el mismo resultado. Aquí, en vez de inicializar variables para iterar, uso `fetc_assoc()` de `php`. [Documentación aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');

    //Setear la colación utf8
    $mysqli -> set_charset("utf8");

    // comprobar la conexión
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
        exit();
    }

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM familias";
    $familias = $mysqli->query($sql1);
?>

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="TDTQVS">Productos</h1>
    <br>
    <?php while ($familia = $familias->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
        <h2 class="TDTQVS"><?= $familia["nombre_familia"]; ?></h2>
        <table class="table TabRegistro">
            <th>Nombre del producto</th>
            <th>Descripción del producto</th>
            <th>Imagen del producto</th>
            <th>Familia</th>
            <th>Oferta</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <?php
                $idFamilia = $familia["id_familia"];
                $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_familia = $idFamilia";
                $productos = $mysqli->query($sql2);
            ?>
            <?php while ($producto = $productos->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
              <tr>
                <td><?= $producto["nombre_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["descripcion_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["imagen_producto"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["id_familia"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["nombre_oferta"]; ?></td>
                <td><?= $producto["precio"]; ?></td> 
              </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </table> 
        <hr>
        <hr> 
   <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<!-- cerrar la conexión -->
<?php $mysqli->close(); ?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda DjCrazy pero con el foreach no me funcionó,me tiro errores por todos los lados en que probé el código, que mas puedo hacer??, sigo diciendo que el while funciona para esto pero lo que no se es como hacer que los dos ciclos funcionen de manera correcta....

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta con un ejemplo completo y una captura del resultado. Te dejo las dos opciones `foreach` y `while` para que escojas la que mejor se acomode a tus gustos.

Comment: Uy! compa, no había notado que es en `sqlserver` y mi respuesta está orientada a `mysql`. Te dejo el [link de la documentación de](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) `php` para `sqlserver`. La verdad cambia muy poco respecto a mi respuesta. Intenta hacerlo y si no te funciona, comenta y elimino mi respuesta. Mil disculpas por no leer el encabezado de la pregunta y ten en cuenta para futuras preguntas, agregar una etiqueta del motor de BD que usas.

Comment: Bien, espero redimirme con esta última edición. Adáptalo a tu código y si aún así no te funciona, comenta por favor.

Comment: Ya he visto la documentación de sql server días atrás y nada.... sigue igual...se supone que con la lógica que se esta usando debería funcionar, lo que me di cuenta es que ese mismo error ha pasado usando mysql y tienen una función de nombre **mysql_data_seek**, esta función hace que el puntero interno al siguiente resultado, cabe aclarar que ya esa función está obsoleta, pero me doy cuenta que los que necesito es hacer que el puntero interno apunte al siguiente resultado,al saben de alguna función en sql server que funcione o como resolver este problema con los while??? gracias DjCrazy!!

Comment: Por cierto, la imagen que puso como resultado del código usan mysql es el mismo que deseo sacar con sql server!!

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103301/discussion-between-djcrazy-and-aguero).